# umet dependency while apt-get install ros-kinect-desktop-full

Tags: 16.04, dependencies, ros

I follow the ROS Kinetic Install [Tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu) on my ubuntu16.04,but i met the problem while

```
elon@elonWorkStation:~/Script$ sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-desktop-full
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-kinetic-desktop-full : Depends: ros-kinetic-desktop but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: ros-kinetic-perception but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: ros-kinetic-simulators but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: ros-kinetic-urdf-tutorial but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have try every method I can find but no luck. This is my /etc/apt/sources.list

```
deb http://mirrors.aliyun.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe restricted multiverse
```

I have worked on the problem for about a day. I can I fix it.

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! please [edit] your post to include the output of ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d Thank you for helping us help you!

Answer (score 0):

INFO: I have recently updated to Ubuntu 18.01 bionic, I am also trying to install ros melodic.

SHORT ANSWER:

For me it worked to install libcurl4, libcurl4-openssl-dev

LONG ANSWER:

Hi,

I have got the same problem that you, which make me feel better that I amnot alone. The one way around is to use the installation from source http://wiki.ros.org/melodic/Installation/Source. Then, they provide a tool called rosdep that can be used to resolve dependencies:

rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro melodic -y

EDIT: If trying to install kinetic must be: kinetic

And then the error contained more information such as that libcurl4, and libcurl4-openssl-dev were missing.
I installed.
sudo apt-get install libcurl4
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev

And then changed to install again the recommended version in:
http://wiki.ros.org/melodic/Installation/Ubuntu

I have been digging in the internet and could not been able to find any other fixing that work for me.

Regards,